# Migrate my logic to change my XML from logic into XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I have an  logic in code that I want to move to XSLT . One of the reasons is I believe that XSLT might be faster than looping and checking elements in code and replacing things than logic.

Here is sample XML

```
  <link-to link-ref="file/path1">
    <cite value=fie/path1">Transformed File</cite>
  </link-to>
  <link-to link-ref="\file\path2">
    <cite value="LEAVE \file\path2">DEFAULT FILE</cite>
  </link-to>
```

This is logic

```
  contents.search('link-to[@link-ref]/cite').each do |node|
    link_href = node['value']
    unless link_href.start_with?('LEAVE') // if value does not start with leave transform it
      link_href.gsub!(bad_characters, '/'=>'%252F', "'"=>'%2527') // take care of characters that will be issue
      link_text = node.inner_html
      node.parent.replace("<a href='#{root_path}citation/#{link_href}'>#{link_text}</a>")
    end
```

This is end result

```
<a href=\"/citation/file/path1">Transformed File</a>
<link-to link-ref="\file\path2">
  <cite value="LEAVE \file\path2">DEFAULT FILE</cite>
</link-to>
```

Can some one help me figurer out how to do this logic in xslt.

Comment: for the `link-to` iteration you could use match `<xsl:template match="link-to">`, to get the cite value, you could use  `<xsl:value-of select="cite"/>` ... to apply the values you can use `<xsl:apply-templates select="xpath" />`.  but what is your choice of the xslt parser, i'd choose libxml / libxslt, which is open source, but afaik still XSLT 1. 
what have you tried?

Comment: I am pretty new to XSLT in general but as far as I do know we are using open source XSLT 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You  need a root element in your XML

```
<links>
  <link-to link-ref="file/path1">
    <cite value="file/path1">Transformed File</cite>
  </link-to>
  <link-to link-ref="\file\path2">
    <cite value="LEAVE \file\path2">DEFAULT FILE</cite>
  </link-to>
 </links>
```

and then apply this XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" />
    </xsl:template>

<!-- only match the link-to elements that don't contain 'LEAVE' in @value -->
    <xsl:template match="link-to[not(contains(cite/@value,'LEAVE'))]">
        <a href="{cite/@value}">
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </a>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```